Capacitance on op-amp input (inverting pin)
I have the following configuration for my amplifier, which is an transimpedance amplifier:

I need to connect my transducer to the inverting pin of my amplifier by using a dip switch to be able to have 4 signals from my amplifier.
Should I use a specific width for my tracks? Microstrips have capacitance and inductance, and having capacitance on the inverting pin of operation amplifiers is not OK as far as I know, and can cause instability.
The length of these tracks can vary from 5 to 25 cm. So, would you please give some remarks to make this routing as good as possible?


What is the impedance of the transducer? Is it on a cable, if so how long is it?  Should it, in fact, be operated into a matching impedance, not a short circuit?

@ Tim Williams thank you for the comment, the transducer has 1nF capacitance and 1.2 K resistance. Then @ 3MHz its impedance is almost 53 Ohm. It is directly connected to my PCB without any cable.  The FX1 connector is the place that the transducer is connected, the transducer is on a small PCB that can be connected with FX1 to my PCB.

The 1 nF of transducer capacitance will probably swamp out any trace capacitance.  Capacitance on the input of a transimpedance amplifier usually isn't a stability problem like it can be on the output, but it can cause noise peaking since it causes the noise gain to increase with frequency.

@ John D Thank you John, how about inductance? should I be worry about inductance?

@Andromeda I doubt trace inductances would be much of a factor with a sensor that has 1 nF of capacitance.
